# Git log, show only entries since last pull

Tags: git, git-log

So I used to pull things from a remote repo and then run `git log` to see latest changes. But keeping track of the previous state in my head was a bit annoying, so I discovered `git log orig_head..head`, supposedly this shows you only entries between previous pull and the latest.

But then one day it stopped working for me. Apparently it stopped working for some repositories. For some this still works. Does anyone have a clue why it wouldn't work sometimes?

Comment: Are you using lowercase like this, instead of all-caps `ORIG_HEAD` and `HEAD`? (If so, I presume you're on Windows or MacOS.) If you are, have you done a `git worktree add` and are you in one of the added work-trees?

Comment: was the results of the command when it stopped working?

Answer (score 3):

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem) :

> ORIG_HEAD is created by commands that move your HEAD **in a drastic way**, to record the position of the HEAD before their operation, so that you can easily change the tip of the branch back to the state before you ran them.

*(emphasis mine)*

So depending on the operation, `ORIG_HEAD` is not updated each time `HEAD` points to a new commit.

You can alternatively use `HEAD@{1}` to refer to the last entry in `HEAD`'s reflog, it'll be more robust.

---

(Granted, this doesn't answer the part about why it seemed to work consistently on some repos for some time and now fails on part of them.)